# Using try/except with if/else statements

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, try-except

I need to get the average of a set of numbers from user input, but also need to use try and except for entering "bob" that outputs an error message, then let's them try again.

I've tried having the try/except in the if/else statement, but it just produces the error message after the first integer input (wrong). Now, I have it set up to run the user input, produce the average, and provide the error message if "bob" is entered. BUT it needs to let the user keep trying, not end the program.

```py
try:
    val = int(input("Enter how many numbers: "))
    sums = 0
    if val == 0:
        average = "error"
        print("error, try again")
    else:
        for value in range(val):
            num = float(input("enter a number: "))
            sums = sums + float(num)
            average = sums / val
            num = "bob"
            #num = float(input("enter a number: "))
        print("Average: " + str(average))
except:
    print("error, try again")
```

expected:
Number of numbers: 3
Enter number: 2.5
Enter number: bob
error, try again
Enter number: 1.5
Enter number: 3.5
Average: 2.5

actual:
Enter how many numbers: 3
enter a number: 2.5
enter a number: bob
error, try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the try/except only on the lines of code where you expect an error. In this case, when you cast the user input to int or float.

Since you are using a for loop, you will miss a number in case of invalid input. a while loop is better in this case.

Here is something that will work:

```
val = input("Enter how many numbers: ")

while not val.isdigit() or val == '0':
    print("error, try again")
    val = input("Enter how many numbers: ")
val = int(val)
valid_nums = 0
sums = 0
while valid_nums < val:
    try:
        num = float(input("enter a number: "))
        valid_nums += 1
        sums += num
    except ValueError:
        print("error, try again")
        continue
print("Average:", sums/val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **try/catch** inside a loop.